# Android: Random number generator to select a phrase and phrases management

Tags: android, arrays, string, text

I am asking for a specific scenario.

I have a lot short quotes that I want to randomly draw to display.  Is there a previously written good sample code somewhere for this?

The quotes right now I have in a text editor.  Should I store it as a text file in the Android project and load it as a text file line by line and load it to an string array?  If so How do I do that (loading quotes from text file in Android JAVA)?

Should I also store it as String.xml for each quote?  I ask that this b/c I think its very inefficient b/c of the XML tags would big up the file size..

Pls advise and Pls excuse my ignorance to some matters here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use text file and in that put your quotes in this formate

```
string:string:string
string:string:string
string:string:string
```

Now read that file and convert it into array like this

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
src.useDelimiter(":");

while (src.hasNext()) {
    lines.add(src.nextLine());
    // replace above line with array
}
String[] lineArray = new String[lines.size()];
lines.toArray(lineArray);
```

And select random quote from this

```
Random r = new Random();
Log.i("selected quote","quote : " + lineArray[r.nextInt(lines.size())]);
```

Hope this will help you  :)

Comment: great stuff... is there an efficient way to share this code to be used among like 5 different activities?  I ask b/c I know I might have to create a class and call a class function to populate this array over and over again when switching among the activities in the UI... is there a way to load/populate the array only once and share it among the various Activities?  tnx

Comment: Yes You can make lineArray to static so that you can use it in all Activity